# MS Access 2016 Open Record on Click and Then Be Able To Go To Previous Or Next Record

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, events, macros

Long time reader first time poster here. I have basic knowledge of access coding but nothing fancy. Anyways here it goes. I have coded on click from a Tubular List in access of our products table to be able to open up a certain specific file. When I click on a product name or SKU it does just that and opens that specific record for me called (Product Profile Form). AWESOME! I have on that Product Profile Form Next and Previous Buttons to go to the next or previous records. But if I go through the Product List and click on the Product Title. It Opens and If I then click Next or Previous record Button it first shows a blank Product Profile but on the next click it says "You cant go to that specific record" in a pop up. The Code Macro I have on the Tubular Product List Form is

/ Form Name: Parent Product Profile Form /
View: Form /
Filter Name: /
Where Condition=: ="[Product Parent SKU]='" & [Product Parent SKU] & "'" /
Data Mode: Edit /
Window Mode: Normal /

Parent Product SKU is The Primary Key Field Name in my ParentProductTable
I have tried and tried to figure this out for hours online and here.
Thank you all for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved it myself and if anyone else has this same issue the resolution is this. Make a command button on your form. You will have to run a few different macros for the on click event for the command Button. For the Next Record Button After clicking where you want your command button to go on your form the Command button wizard will pop up. Choose Record Navigation in the categories box and then choose Go To Next Record in the Actions Box. Finish the Command Button Wizard. Then Right click the button and choose Build an event. This will open the Macro Tools. Click add new action and choose the Macro RemoveFilterSort.After that if you hover over the macro RemoveFilterSort you will see green arrows to place your macros in the order you want. Click the green arrows up until it is first at the top. Click Save and then exit. Now you should be able to go to the next record. Do the same for the previous record except in the command wizard pop up choose Record Navigation in the Categories area and then choose Go To Previous Record instead of like before we chose Go To Next Record. I am using Access 2016. What you basically did is told the button to remove the filters before moving on to the next or previous record. If you dont want to make command buttons and use the access supplied navigation buttons at the bottom. You can make a command button with the macro RemoveFilterSort only and you will have to click this button to remove the filter then you can click the Access supplied navigation button. I hope this helps someone.